# Mootools: Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am trying to send a simple ajax post request using Mootools but I'm only receiving the error message in the title and it seems it doesn't send the data correctly (the request gets canceled).

Here is the html:

```
<form id="form_5" name="form_5" action="someajaxfile.php" onsubmit="jsfunction(this,5);return false;" method="post">....</form>
```

And here is the javascript function called when submitted:

```
function jsfunction(form,eventId) {
        var container = $('form_contents' + eventId);

        form.send({
            update: container,
            evalScripts: true,
            onComplete: function() {
                container.removeClass('ajax-loading');
            }
        });

    }
```

I've tried to add stuff like `headers: {'X-Request': 'JSON'},` to the send function but nothing seems to change the error. One wierd thing is tho, that in chrome under the network tab I can see two requests:

```
someajax.php
/somefolder
POST
302
Found
text/html
mootools.js:247
Script
354B
0B
2ms
2ms
2ms0


someajax.php
/somefolder
GET
(canceled)
Pending
http://localhost:8888/somefolder/someajax.php
Redirect
13B
0B
0ms
0.0 days
```

The question is: why can't I send the data, what happens and why and it there any good solution to my problem?

Comment: What version of mootools is that?.. I didn't knew that you could make a Request directly from the form element... maybe i'm wrong but usually you need to create a instance of the Request class or Request.JSON if you need a json response, o even Form.Request

Comment: Obviously you can, just got confirmed that it works on the stage server (which is not localhost) even if the error message is displayed. The problem in creating a new instance of Form.Request class is that the html is generated. Would still be interested to know if anyone got a solution to my problem without rewriting the function too much.

Comment: No one at the office knows what version it is by the way :P

Comment: @pleasedontbelong it's part of More's Form.Request http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/Form.Request#Form-Request:send

Comment: @dombenoit i dont think so, in the doc `myFormRequest` is an instance of Form.Request, not the form itself

Comment: to setup the request instance beforehand, `form.set('send', optionsObj)`. you are within the same domain and port and protocol, aren't you? just checking... - sounds like a response after a `GET OPTIONS` which happens for CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is: why can't I send the data, what happens and why and
>   it there any good solution to my problem?

Your problem is the combination of Chrome+Local and the *--allow-file-access-from-files* restriction.

To try:

- Run those files in chrome (dev) in a 'safe' enviroment whith the
  command --allow-file-access-from-files
- Run your file in another browser

Answer (score 1):

hmmm After trying a few things, I dont think its possible to make an "AJAX" request directly from the **form element** (but if I'm wrong I'd like to see an example of how that works n_n)

Usually I use an instance of Request (or any of it's extensions: Request.JSON, Request.JSONP, Form.Request).

I'd do it like this:

```
function myfunction(form){
    new Request({
      url:form.action,
      data:form,
      onSuccess:function(result){
          console.log(result);
      }
    }).send();
    return false;
};
```

A working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pCUKe/